# Confusion about four concurrent dispatch queues provided by system in GCD

Tags: ios, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

[Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW5) says:

> The system provides each application with four concurrent dispatch queues. These queues are global to the application and are differentiated only by their priority level.

[This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1) says:

> The system also provides you with several concurrent queues. These queues are linked with their own Quality of Service (QoS) class.

Run these lines of code:

```
println(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0))
println(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0))
println(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY, 0))
println(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0))
```

I got this:

```
<OS_dispatch_queue_root: com.apple.root.user-interactive-qos[0x10c2b9000]>
<OS_dispatch_queue_root: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos[0x10c2b8e80]>
<OS_dispatch_queue_root: com.apple.root.utility-qos[0x10c2b8b80]>
<OS_dispatch_queue_root: com.apple.root.background-qos[0x10c2b8a00]>
```

So, are the four concurrent dispatch queues respectively linked with `QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE`, `QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED`, `QOS_CLASS_UTILITY` and `QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND`?

In addition, through playing with `dispatch_get_global_queue`, I got that `QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED`(.value=25) corresponds to `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH`(=2), `QOS_CLASS_UTILITY`(.value=17) correspond to `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW`(=-2), `QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND`(.value=9) correspond to `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND`(=INT16_MIN).

But when I call this:

```
println(dispatch_get_global_queue(5, 0))
```

I got this:

```
<OS_dispatch_queue_root: com.apple.root.maintenance-qos[0x1110ce880]>
```

`maintenance` is none of the four QoS mentioned above, so there are at least five (I'm not sure whether more exist) concurrent dispatch queues provided by the system, why does Apple say four?